# Why the bean bean gcpProjectIdProvider is available in two classpaths and causing error?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am geting the below error when i run my spring boot application. Not sure what is the rootcause. Please help me to find the rootcause and resolution.

### Pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.4.8
 

com.example
firestoretest
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
firestoretest
Demo project for Spring Boot firestore

<java.version>11</java.version>
<spring-cloud-gcp.version>2.0.3</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-hateoas


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web


com.google.cloud
spring-cloud-gcp-starter

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-datastore -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-datastore</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> 
    
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>20.6.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### Error

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

The bean 'gcpProjectIdProvider', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/core/GcpContextAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/google/cloud/spring/autoconfigure/core/GcpContextAutoConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

Comment: You can refer to the StackOverflow question[1] where the similar error has been resolved by the community.
[1] : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203051/redis-consider-renaming-one-of-the-beans-or-enabling-overriding-by-setting-spr

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 GcpContextAutoConfiguration implementations.

- One provided by `com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure`
- One provided by `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure`

You can avoid this issue by replacing dependency:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-datastore</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

With this one:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-datastore</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Btw, I discovered this issue in my own project by using Maven's [Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/). In my case, running `mvn dependency:tree | grep gcp-auto` produced the following results, clearly showing the 2 competing implementations on my classpath:

```
[INFO] |     |  \- com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.8.RELEASE:compile
```

**EDIT**
Ok so I found this [migration guide](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/index.html#migration-guide-from-spring-cloud-gcp-1-x-to-2-x) in the spring docs which does state:

> Change Group IDs to `com.google.cloud`

Spring offers further explanation in their [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2019/07/24/simplifying-the-spring-cloud-release-train):

> ... the Spring Cloud team has decided to move to a model that slims down the release train, allowing us to address the downsides whilst keeping all the perceived benefits. The proposal is that IaaS providers will host and maintain their code in their own GitHub organizations.

Since this happened in 2019, apparently we are just behind the times. Though to be fair, the documentation online currently is quite inconsistent.

Comment: thank you so much. You probably just saved me a whole day of banging my head against the Dependency Analyzer tool in IntelliJ.

Still a relevant answer if you're working on Spring Boot v3 (Spring v6) in 2023 and happen to misguidedly land using the `org.springframework.cloud` provided artifact.