# Firebase Admin SDK integration is failing when used with the "spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql" dependency

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore, spring-cloud-gcp

```
#implementation "com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql:3.4.7"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.1.1"
```

When I comment out the first line in the bootstrap file, the following issue arises

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.firestore.GcpFirestoreAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.spring.core.GcpProjectIdProvider' that could not be found.
```

I have to use both of the dependencies what solution would you suggest?

Comment: Have you checked this similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68329352/why-the-bean-bean-gcpprojectidprovider-is-available-in-two-classpaths-and-causin) as `dependencies` should have a value of `implementation("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql")`? Additional info can be found [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/index.html#cloud-sql).

Answer (score 0):

I have added configuration in application.properties and it fixed my issue.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      firestore:
        enabled: false
```